# Flickering in tables / Interspace between a line within a field

Tags: tables, tabu, colortbl

I have two problems with my table:
When zooming in and out with my Adobe pdf Reader, the table lines are flickering and sometimes not visible. 
The second problem is the Interspace between the lines. After using "tabu" instead of "tabular" (I need the tabu package for the rowfont command) the space between two lines in a field gets bigger (red circle).

How can i fix the two problems?
`
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}
    \definecolor{hd_dblue}{RGB}{0,65,120}
    \definecolor{hd_grey}{RGB}{231,232,236}
    \definecolor{hd_lblue}{RGB}{0,160,230}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table}[H]
        \taburulecolor{white}
        \begin{tabu}{|>{\columncolor{hd_lblue}}>{\color{white}}P{4cm}| >{\columncolor{hd_grey}}>{\color{white}}r|>{\columncolor{hd_grey}}>{\color{white}}r|>{\columncolor{hd_grey}}>{\color{white}}c|} 
            \hline
            \rowcolor{hd_lblue}Lizenz& einmalige Kosten& Kosten für drei Jahre&User pro Lizenz\\
            \hline
            \hline
        \rowfont{\color{hd_dblue}} \textcolor{white}{NVIDIA Virt Appl Subscription CCU}& - & \$30,00& 1\\
            \hline
            \rowfont{\color{hd_dblue}} \textcolor{white}{NVIDIA Virt WS Subscription CCU}&-&\$750,00& 1\\
            \hline
            \rowfont{\color{hd_dblue}} \textcolor{white}{VMware Horizon View Standard CCU}&  2.325,00\euro& 1.467,00\euro& 10\\
            \hline
            \rowfont{\color{hd_dblue}} \textcolor{white}{Citrix XenApp Advanced Edition CCU}& \$3.050,00& \$2.100,00& 10\\
            \hline
        \rowfont{\color{hd_dblue}} \textcolor{white}{Citrix XenDesktop VDI Edition CCU}&  \$1.650,00&\$1.350,00& 10\\
            \hline
        \end{tabu}
        \caption{Kosten der Lizenzen}
        \label{tab:cost_software}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the picture you can also see the missing lines:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you need to use `\rowfont`? You are using `\textcolor` anyway, so you could do a `\color` before and after the table and should be fine.

Comment: I used this command, because I have about 10 tables with many rows and columns dont want to insert the \textcolor at any single field. This is the more automated way :D.

Comment: What about using it in the column definition and just adjusting the headline?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a latex professional. Some things of this code is just code from google. Can you provide me an working example?

Comment: You will see *flickering* with any viewer at some point. Das is einfach so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rather quick and dirty solution. That uses `setspace` to solve your issue and has improved color management (now in column header).

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
    \definecolor{hd_dblue}{RGB}{0,65,120}
    \definecolor{hd_grey}{RGB}{231,232,236}
    \definecolor{hd_lblue}{RGB}{0,160,230}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table}
        \taburulecolor{white}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{
            \columncolor{hd_lblue}}>{\color{hd_dblue}\begin{spacing}{.8}}P{4cm}<{\end{spacing}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}| >{
                \columncolor{hd_grey}\color{hd_dblue}}r|>{
                    \columncolor{hd_grey}\color{hd_dblue}}r|>{
                        \columncolor{hd_grey}\color{hd_dblue}}c|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{hd_lblue}\textcolor{white}{Lizenz}& \textcolor{white}{einmalige Kosten}& \textcolor{white}{Kosten für drei Jahre}&\textcolor{white}{User pro Lizenz}\\\hline\hline
            \textcolor{white}{NVIDIA Virt Appl Subscription CCU}& - & \$30,00& 1\\\hline
            \textcolor{white}{NVIDIA Virt WS Subscription CCU}&-&\$750,00& 1\\\hline
            \textcolor{white}{VMware Horizon View Standard CCU}&  2.325,00\euro& 1.467,00\euro& 10\\\hline
            \textcolor{white}{Citrix XenApp Advanced Edition CCU}& \$3.050,00& \$2.100,00& 10\\\hline
            \textcolor{white}{Citrix XenDesktop VDI Edition CCU}&  \$1.650,00&\$1.350,00& 10\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Kosten der Lizenzen}
        \label{tab:cost_software}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend to make a new thread with the other problem?

Comment: @tiga05 Probably yes, and maybe don't call it "flickering". Maybe just "Problems with table lines (reader)" or something like that.